# Publishing to shinyapps.io from RStudio reading all files in directory, not just checkboxed ones

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I've uploaded apps to shinyapps.io in the past with little issue from RStudio. I have my shinyApp.R file (contains both server and ui) as well as the two CSV files that are used for it in the same directory.

When I click "Publish" I get the popup window as shown here:
[Link to pic of check box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQqyC.png).
I only select the .R file and the two data files to upload but when I click "Publish" I get errors about relative file references in two files that I'm not even trying to upload and have nothing to do with the app (see here [Image of error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82RIZ.png).

It seems like rsconnect/deployApp is reading through every file in the parent and children directories regardless of whether or not I clicked the checkbox next to it. Anyone else have this issue?